# Can not send email through gmail

Tags: email, gmail

I have a contact page that is supposed to send emails through gmail.

Here is the code:

```
func sendContactEmail(subject string, email string, message string)  {

    auth := smtp.PlainAuth(
        "contact form submit",
        "myaccount@gmail.com",
        "mypassword",
        "smtp.gmail.com",
    )
    // Connect to the server, authenticate, set the sender and recipient,
    // and send the email all in one step.


    body := subject + "\r\n" + email  +"\r\n" + message

    msg := "Subject: Contact us" + "\r\n\r\n" + body + "\r\n"

    err := smtp.SendMail(
        "smtp.gmail.com:587",
        auth,
        "activation@mysite.org",
        []string{"myaccount@gmail.com"},        
        []byte(msg),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return
}

func ContactPOST(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // Get form values
    subject := r.FormValue("subject")   
    email := r.FormValue("email")
    message := r.FormValue("message")
    go sendContactEmail(subject, email, message)
    // Display the thank you page
    v := view.New(r)
    v.Name = "contact/thanks"
    v.Render(w)
    return 
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
contact.go:41: 534 5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbti
5.7.14 HcGWI2H6QjVTNjHS4X49PcBxQQGNhL9TKnzdQxqYgeUXkWxpHj90RSAaIbI-ySSrKFTV4q
5.7.14 IVZeXExVeqhuZnPhtvUtx9p5Ly7gBxwFLzrrgWcm4NZ3_vhDOWiH-uDsPb5eoa4rbYCepd
5.7.14 PlD9kBBz1dAlhdRDJ7mwqsUMJUV7MHTgNWqTcT_R89Uq9oYtwurtmGAuv2YAkPTCBtPwXq
5.7.14 9ooL5edn_sTI6WJW72sK2ilMCIUB0> Please log in via your web browser and
5.7.14 then try again.
5.7.14  Learn more at
5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 63sm17219759wmg.2 - gsmtp
```

The weird thing is that the form works fine when I send email on my development machine, and the error occurs only when the app is deployed on the VPS where the http server just dies after showing the `thank you` page.

I have also tried calling `sendContactEmail` without the goroutine but still get the same error.

I appreciate your hints to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

My organization had a similar problem. We had to log into our admin email console at gmail and turn on smtp relay access for our IP so the web authentication was no longer necessary. See here for help.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en

---

Also appreciate the clarification. You are absolutely correct that for personal accounts, you can go to that link (https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) and be able to have suitable authentication granted via mail relay.

Comment: Well, I use a personal account (not G suite) and I set `Access for less secure apps` on.

Comment: Update: as per suggestions on the google's troubleshooting link visiting this page `https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha` solved the issue. Please update your answer and I'll accept it.